# Regular expression check first name? ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have regular expression that should check argument first name. My string can contain `'.,(space)-`. I have tested and regular expression indicated `true` for all but one character. If I fro example have name like `Ben's` regular expression returned `false`. Here is my regex:

```
<cfset fname = len(trim(arguments.fname)) AND REFind("(?i)^ *[a-z][a-z' .,-]{0,29} *$",trim(arguments.fname),true) EQ 1>
```

I'm not sure if something else is causing my regex to fail. If anyone see where is the problem in my code please let me know. thank you!

Comment: If you use `trim(arguments.fname)`, then there is no need using `space*` in the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Problem is single quote/apostrophe. If I pass hard coded value for example Ben's that returns true but if I pass the same value with argument that returns false. I'm confused where is the problem in my code...

Comment: The problem might be anywhere else if the input string has no `'`, but some `&apos;`  instead.

Comment: Is there a way to work around this problem? When I check Network call in my dev tools value looks like this Ben's.

Comment: I do not know. Debug your code and see where it starts failing.

Comment: Will that command actually execute?

Comment: I found the problem. On client side I use JQuery to send the form data via AJAX. For some reason single quote is different once data is checked on the server side. I'm not sure why but there is obvious difference between two quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.

```
patternOnlyCertainCharacters = "[^ 0-9a-zA-Z.\-]";
testString = "1.- ~";
writeoutput(refind(patternOnlyCertainCharacters, testString));
```

Between the square brackets,

```
^ is an anchor
There is a space between the ^ and 0 characters
0-9a-zA-Z allows any number or letter, upper or lower case
. is a period
\- is a hyphen, escaped by a backslash
```

Your job is to properly add other characters you want to allow, such as a comma, and decide how to apply the results to your incoming string.